# Translucent material/shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I want to achieve this result.

Light passes from thin areas of object (lower density) and cannot pass from higher density areas.

Is it possible? I also want to export it as WebGL to use it in web App.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I never tried myself but as far as I know it's possible. I've come across this post before:

http://www.farfarer.com/blog/2012/09/11/translucent-shader-unity3d/

It's a bit old but it may be a good starting point. There's a link to an old GDC presentation as well explaining a bit how this stuff works which may be helpful.

If I'll ever going to have the freetime I'll try it at home, sadly the coming holidays kept me away from working with Unity recently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i have seen this and it is pretty good but it applies same effect on whole object and i need something that consider density as well, like same object with different density (lower density areas should glow). Thanks @PockeTiger